# android bluetooth obd2 application development

Tags: android, bluetooth, obd-ii

I want to create an Android application to connect to the car through bluetooth, using an `EML327` device (OBD2). I am very new to this area, and I've searched information, but I don't know how to start and what I need for this. I've installed Android Studio.

First question would be, do I need another tool to install? Every sample I took from internet, is not working on my side, and I can not figure it out why.

Comment: Start with getting the Bluetooth chat application working and learning Android basics

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question and its scope is a bit beyond a StackOverflow answer.

To write a ScanTool app, you first need to learn about the communication stack involved, e.g. Bluetooth (LE), serial communication w/ ELM327, and SAE J1979.

Start off by opening a serial communication channel to your adapter and see whether a `ATZ` returns an `ELM327` response. Then we can talk about the further steps.